# How do I use joblib to parallelize a Selenium scraping task? (A non-working example)

Tags: python, selenium, joblib

I have a task that requires extracting data from the Indian 2011 Census. I am using Selenium and have a working script (featured below), but I am trying to use the joblib library and Parallel to parallelize the task.  I do not receive an error when I run this script, and I do observe my processors active in my task manager (Windows 10), but I do not see any files saved from running this program and it continues to run long after a non-parallel version would have completed.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks so much. BTW, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ASDEuOJEQro20CrWOWYc-c4xOFpiyXdF/view?usp=sharing) is the link to the input dataset for this program.

The first four records of the

```
import time
import re
import string
import urllib.parse
import pandas
import numpy
import os
import csv
import joblib

from selenium import webdriver
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

path = 'C:/Users/d.wm.mclaughlin/Dropbox/research/india'
os.chdir(path)

input_df = pandas.read_excel("file_path/villages_3109_UTTAR PRADESH_12_003.xlsx", "Sheet1")

def downloadFunction(x):
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('C:/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs.exe')
    url = "url"
    driver.get(url);

    selected_state = str(input_df['state_no'][x])
    selected_district = str(input_df['dist_no'][x])
    selected_block = str(input_df['block_no'][x]).zfill(3)
    selected_pan = str(input_df['pan'][x]).zfill(4)

    selected_state_name = input_df['state'][x]
    selected_dist_name = input_df['district'][x]
    selected_block_name = input_df['block'][x]
    selected_pan_name = input_df['village'][x]

    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ddl_state"))
    select.select_by_value(selected_state)

    distSelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ddl_dist"))
    distSelect.select_by_value(selected_district)

    blkSelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ddl_blk"))
    blkSelect.select_by_value(selected_block)

    panSelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ddl_pan"))
    panSelect.select_by_value(selected_pan)                                                                                                                                                                    
    button_list = ['#RadioButtonList1_0', '#RadioButtonList1_1', '#RadioButtonList1_2']
    button_names = ['auto_inclusion', 'auto_exclusion', 'other']
    for b in range(0,1):
        selected_button = button_list[b]
        selected_button_name = button_names[b]
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(selected_button).click()
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#Button1').click()

        if('No Record Found !!!' in driver.page_source):
            print('No Record Found !!!')
        else:
            ae = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#form1 > div:nth-child(4) > center:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(1)').text
            if(ae == ''): ae = 0
            ai = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#form1 > div:nth-child(4) > center:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2)').text
            if(ai == ''): ai = 0
            oth = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#form1 > div:nth-child(4) > center:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(3)').text
            if(oth == ''): oth = 0
            dep = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#form1 > div:nth-child(4) > center:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(4)').text
            if(dep == ''): dep = 0
            ae = int(ae)
            ai = int(ai)
            oth = int(oth)
            dep = int(dep)
            ai_dep = ai + dep

            records = [ai_dep, ae, oth]
            selected_record = records[b]

            table_number = round(selected_record/45)
            table_numbers = list(range(1, (1+(table_number)*3), 3))
            data = []
            for data_tab in table_numbers:
                table_address = '#Div1 > table:nth-child(' + str(data_tab) + ')'
                #print(table_address)
                for tr in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(table_address):
                    # CONTINUE FROM HERE!!!
                    #print(tr == driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#Div1 > table:nth-child(" + str(data_tab) + ") > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)"))
                    #"#Div1 > table:nth-child(" + str(data_tab) + ") > tbody > tr:nth-child(2)"
                    #"#Div1 > table:nth-child(" + str(data_tab) + ") > tbody > tr:nth-child(3)"

                    tds = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
                    if tds:
                        data.append([td.text for td in tds])

            #newArray = numpy.array(data)
            for listItem in range(0,len(data)):
                if(listItem > 0):
                    data[listItem] = data[listItem][18:len(data[listItem])]
                    #print(len(data[listItem]))

            flat_data = [item for sublist in data for item in sublist]
            newArray = numpy.array(flat_data)
            dataRows = int(numpy.array(flat_data).size / 9)
            rowsTimesColumns = (dataRows * 9)
            test = pandas.DataFrame(newArray.reshape(dataRows,9), columns=['no',    'hh_name', 'gender', 'age', 'sc', 'fm_name', 'depriv_count', 'ai_d_code', 'total_mem'])
            file_path = 'C:/Users/d.wm.mclaughlin/Dropbox/research/lpg_india/data/secc/secc' + '_' + selected_state + '_' + '_' + selected_district + '_' + '_' + selected_block + '_' + '_' + selected_pan + '_' + '_' + selected_button_name + '.xlsx'
            test.to_excel(file_path, 'Sheet1')
    return print(x);

tester = Parallel(n_jobs=3)(delayed(downloadFunction)(in_val) for in_val in range(1, 10))
```

Comment: How much memory is it using and how much does your machine have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have enough memory to run this without using swap you should take a look at the documentation. From https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html. Pay particular attention to the last line.

> **Warning**
>
> Under Windows, it is important to protect the main loop of code to
>   avoid recursive spawning of subprocesses when using joblib.Parallel.
>   In other words, you should be writing code like this:

```
import ....

def function1(...):
    ...

def function2(...):
    ...

... if __name__ == '__main__':
    # do stuff with imports and functions defined about
    ...
```

> No code should run outside of the “if **name** == ‘**main**’” blocks,
>   only imports and definitions.

If it is a memory issue please read the rest of the page. You could start with

```
from joblib.pool import has_shareable_memory
```

and changing your last line to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tester = Parallel(n_jobs=3, max_nbytes=1e2)(delayed(downloadFunction, has_shareable_memory)(in_val) for in_val in range(1, 10))
```

But I'm guessing that not much of your memory consumption can be shared.

You could also add some garbage collection to save memory:

```
import gc
```

before your return statement delete all unnecessary variables and add

```
del driver
del test
del newArray
del data
# and all the rest
_ = gc.collect()
```

but be aware that this will not garbage collect the underlying executables memory e.g. PhantomJS